# Is $f$ injective in $W$?

Tags: functional-analysis

If

> $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\geqslant \frac 1{2} \|x-y\|$ for any $x, y \in W$

then

> $f$ is injective in $W$

How to prove this? If that inequality is right is it mean that the images are equal or not?

Comment: If the distance between two points is more than zero, then they're not the same point.

Comment: Just to make a comment, I think I saw this in a proof of the Inverse Function Theorem.

Comment: @AdenDong, you are [right](http://math.ucsd.edu/~nwallach/inverse[1].pdf). Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume $f(x) = f(y)$. What is $\|f(x)-f(y)\|$? What can you conclude about $\|x-y\|$?

Comment: Thanks. It's mean that the proof of this expression is in definition of injective function. $f(x) = f(y) => x=y $